# Owner Properties File Location

Tags: java, properties, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, owner

I put my config.properties file in src/test/resources/config.properties at intellij IDE.

When i initiaze this code

```
@Config.Sources({"classpath:config.properties"})
public interface PropertiesManager extends Config {
```

It cannot be found the file but the file is located at target/test-classes/config.properties. It just cannot find the file.

How to declare properly. Thanks. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have same scenario running fine: when you instantiate your config in test, then using properties file from test/resource folter is fine. So you should troubleshoot you build tool like maven or gradle: Why you tests do not find test resources.